# Can I/How to jump back to a specific line of code using while & if-else together?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

I've written my code to work fine, but if the user chooses to try a different output, I'd like to skip the introductory message. For example, if the user chooses to generate a different password, I'd prefer to return to line 11 (the request to enter a length requirement) rather than line 8. (which welcomes the user to the program).

```
import random
import string
import sys

another = True

while another:
8    print("Welcome to the Password Generator!")

# ask user for password length requirement
11    length = int(input("How many characters does your password require?: "))

# initialize character types

    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    capitalize = string.ascii_uppercase
    nums = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation

# combine all char types
    combine = lower + capitalize + nums + symbols

# randomize character types and add length requirement
    randomization = random.sample(combine, length)

# construct the secure password
    secure_pw = "".join(randomization)

# display password
    print(secure_pw)

    another = input("Would you like to generate a different secure password?: ")
    while True:
        if another == 'yes':
            generate = True
            break
        elif another == 'no':
            generate = False
            sys.exit()
        else:
            another = input('Invalid response! Enter "yes" to continue or "no" to exit: ')
```

Comment: Just move line 8 to before the loop.

Comment: Change the `8` to a `6`. :)

Comment: Thank you Tom and Barmar for the comments. Can you imagine how hard I'm beating myself up over such a simple solution?